# Flutter Google Sign In - Email data returns null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-signin

Flutter Google Sign In - Email data returns null. Logs are given below. Thank you very much in advance.

**I use Firebase.**

**I want to login with Google, but** `AuthResult.user.email == null`

***------------------------Log error----------------------------***

```
D/FirebaseAuth( 5302): Notifying id token listeners about user ( 9uKLCYS4VwUbuu77KS27bWjKrlI2 ).
I/flutter ( 5302): Result : Poyraz Çakmak https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mABS7DqwgoIHuFfIwNw_574FRdvxKuvVyNarFo0_w=s96-c null
I/flutter ( 5302): NoSuchMethodError: The method 'indexOf' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 5302): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 5302): Tried calling: indexOf("@")
```

**because User model from userName format. =>  Tried calling: indexOf("@")**

**GoogleSignIn method:**

```
@override
Future<User> login() async {
final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount =
    await MyToolsFirebase.googleSignIn.signIn();

if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
  GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
      await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

  final String idToken = googleSignInAuthentication.idToken;
  final String accessToken = googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken;

  if (idToken != null && accessToken != null) {
    AuthResult authResult = await MyToolsFirebase.firebaseAuth
        .signInWithCredential(GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
            idToken: idToken, accessToken: accessToken));

    return await MyToolsFirebase.saveDbUser(firebaseUser: authResult.user);
  }
}
return null;
}
```

**MyToolsFirebase class:**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:live_chat/Models/User.dart';

class MyToolsFirebase {

  static final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  static final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
    scopes: <String>[
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
    ],
  );

  static final Firestore firestore = Firestore.instance;

  static User userFromFirebaseUser({@required FirebaseUser firebaseUser}) {
    if (firebaseUser == null) return null;
    print("Result : ${firebaseUser.displayName} ${firebaseUser.photoUrl} ${firebaseUser.email}");
    return User(
      uid: firebaseUser.uid,
      email: firebaseUser.email,
      name: firebaseUser.displayName,
      imageURL: firebaseUser.photoUrl,
    );
  }


  static Future<User> saveDbUser({@required FirebaseUser firebaseUser}) async {
    User user = userFromFirebaseUser(firebaseUser: firebaseUser);
    Map userMap = user.toMap();

    await firestore.collection("users").document(user.uid).setData(userMap);
    return await getDbUser(user.uid);
  }

  static Future<User> getDbUser(String uid) async {
    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection("users").document(uid).get();
    print(User.fromMap(documentSnapshot.data).toString());
    return User.fromMap(documentSnapshot.data);
  }
}
```

**User model:**

```
class User {
  final String uid;
  String email;
  String userName;
  String name;
  String imageURL;
  int level;
  DateTime createdAt;
  DateTime updatedAt;

  User({
    @required this.uid,
    @required this.email,
    this.userName,
    this.name,
    this.imageURL,
    this.level,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
  });

  User.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map)
      : this.uid = map["uid"],
        this.email = map["email"],
        this.userName = map["userName"],
        this.name = map["name"],
        this.imageURL = map["imageURL"],
        this.level = int.parse(map["level"]),
        this.createdAt = (map["createdAt"] as Timestamp).toDate(),
        this.updatedAt = (map["updatedAt"] as Timestamp).toDate();

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now().toLocal().toUtc();
    return {
      'uid': this.uid,
      'email': this.email,
      'userName': this.userName ?? this.email.substring(0, this.email.indexOf("@")) + Random().nextInt(1000).toString(),
      'name': this.name,
      'imageURL': this.imageURL ?? "https://www.logolynx.com/images/logolynx/61/61ba01858af7f2ea1184238e9f2771f2.png",
      'level': this.level ?? 1,
      'createdAt': this.createdAt ?? now,
      'updatedAt': this.updatedAt ?? now,
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Any solution??

Comment: same here, I can get user.displayName and user.photoUrl but user.email returns null on assert(user.email != null);

Comment: Facing the same problem. Please tell me the solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
     @override
  Future<User> signInWithGoogle() async {
    GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    GoogleSignInAccount _googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    String _googleUserEmail = _googleUser.email; //BURADA GMAİL OTURUMUNDAN
    // DİREKT OLARAK MAİL ADRESİNİ ALMAYA ÇALIŞIYORUM.
    if (_googleUser != null) {
      GoogleSignInAuthentication _googleAuth = await _googleUser.authentication;
      if (_googleAuth.idToken != null && _googleAuth.accessToken != null) {
        AuthResult sonuc = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(
            GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
                idToken: _googleAuth.idToken,
                accessToken: _googleAuth.accessToken));
        FirebaseUser _user = sonuc.user;
        sonuc.user.updateEmail(_googleUserEmail);
        //Burada Email Adresini Güncelliyoruz.
        //Böylece null olan değer doluyor.
        return _userFromFirebase(_user);
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue. The email address value still shows null.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
Just use `user.providerData[0].email` wherever you are referring to the user email.

Also see this comment - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73343193/20562775